# Bad request for css file after moving wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, lambda, migration

After moving a wordpress site i noticed it didnt look the same so i figured there would be something wrong with a css file, turns out one of the css files of the lambda theme has a bad request and the request URL is constructed weirdly.

The left screen is the one after moving and the right screen is the fully working one that was moved.

[image: See the request-URL (aanvraag-URL), seems to point to a path on the server rather than the actual URL]

Any suggestions?

Comment: obviously the url is wrong, instead of absolute path of the file, try relative path

Comment: i dont know where to set this up, couldnt really find a clue in the database

Comment: show us the live site

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/5uSNA

Comment: ok, here is the problem, do you know how to change the link url? right now it's this inside <head> tag: <link rel="stylesheet" id="lambda-theme-stack-css" href="http://www.laakland.nl/wordpress4/D:/www/laakland.nl/www/wordpress4/wp-content/uploads/lambda/stack-493.css?ver=4.8.1" type="text/css" media="all"> you have to change it to something like this <link rel="stylesheet" id="lambda-theme-stack-css" href="http://www.laakland.nl/wordpress4//wp-content/uploads/lambda/stack-493.css?ver=4.8.1" type="text/css" media="all">

Comment: it's hard to tell how the link url is generated, might be in some script

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is obvious (even thought the solution is not so obvious), There is a incorrect link to the css file on the page:

```
http://www.laakland.nl/wordpress4/D:/www/laakland.nl/www/wordpress4/wp-content/uploads/lambda/stack-493.css?ver=4.8.1
```

Since you said you didnt know where this is coming from, you can start here:

Check `header.php` to see if the CSS is added directly 
Check `functions.php` to see if the CSS file has been added there using `wp_register_style`
Any plugins might have added this too, so you might check there too.

For convenience, use an IDE to search for the text `stack-493.css` on the whole wordpress folder to see if you find the file where it is being added from and then fix the link there.

Comment: i downloaded the website and searched every file in it and only found this: http://imgur.com/a/1UkSP
it's from the duplicator import package.

Comment: this is the only line about styles in functions.php:     wp_enqueue_style( THEME_SHORT . '-child-theme' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( THEME_SHORT . '-theme' ), false, 'all' );

Comment: also nothing related to style in header.php.

i think i should try another way than duplicator to try to migrate the site again

Comment: Thats showing jibberish. If that file is corrupted remove it and replace with the one thats not corrupted.

Comment: it's from a zip file so i think it's compressed or something? And i dont think replacing it matters because it's found in an import package of the duplicator plugin (it's for moving websites and backing them up from wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

Oke i fixed it, i tried the whole migration through duplicator plugin process again, but on step 3 of importing, i removed 'path' (which was "D:/www/xxxx.nl/www/wordpress4") so that after removing that, i thought it wouldnt add the unnecesary part from amit's answer.

thanks all!